# JSON string extraction into field

Tags: python, json, scrapy

Im getting this JSON extract using scrapy, but the desc has the amunt and the amount type on in, this could be g, gr, kg, L, etc. I wan't to know if its possible to extract this data and add it into an additional field.

How could this be achievable either within scrapy or a separate process once he file has been created.

P.S. I'm totally new to JSON and scrapy and I'm learning.

**Current**

```
 {
 'p_desc': ['Coffee 225 g '], 
 'p_price': ['8.00']
 }
```

**Desired**

```
 {
 'p_desc': ['Coffee'],
 'p_amount': [225]
 'p_amount_type': ['g'] 
 'p_price': ['8.00']
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this works if the data has a regular structure (i.e. every desc contains amount and amount type as the last two fields). If not you might have to use regular expressions.

One observation: if each value is unique you don't need a list and for instance you can just use `'Coffee'` instead of `['Coffee']`

```js
jsonData = {
  'p_desc': ['Grain Black Coffee 225 g'],
  'p_price': ['8.00']
}

var p_desc, p_amount, p_amount_type;

[p_amount_type, p_amount,...p_desc] = jsonData['p_desc'][0].split(" ").reverse();
jsonData["p_amount"] = [p_amount];
jsonData["p_amount_type"] = [p_amount_type];
jsonData["p_desc"] = p_desc.join(' ');
console.log(jsonData);
```

Also, you might need to remove trailing white-space from the description.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, the field p_desc is not always 3 values, but the las 2 are always the amount and the amount type.

Black Coffee 100 g
Grain Black Coffee 1 Kg
Sweet White Sugar Cotton Candy 1 ml
etc.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. It solves the problem. How this could be applied to a document.